# Add line numbers to GWT TextArea

Tags: java, gwt, textarea

I've got a view in my GWT project that contains a textarea with some content. Now I'd need to add line numbers to that textarea.

On top of that, I'd like to accomplish this without using **jQuery** or **GWTQuery** if possible.

So far, I've tried implementing two textareas, one with the numbers and one with the content (which looks quite good) but I am not able to synchronize the scrolling properly. Tried something similar to this (code edited for the example):

```
    textAreaCode.addMouseWheelHandler(new MouseWheelHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {
            textAreaNumbers.getElement().setScrollTop(textAreaCode.getElement().getScrollTop());

        }
    });
```

And this solution wouldn't help when clicking the scrollbar buttons instead of using the mouse wheel.

So, any idea how to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A div with content editable might be of interest to do this as well.

Comment: Yes, that could help but my idea was to create it using textareas. I have a working version using GwtQuery, but was interested in a raw GWT solution.